# Populate new dataframe with rowMeans for every four columns minus other rowMeans value

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate my data's means by populating a new dataframe with data corrected by my experiment's blank.
So far, I have created my new data frame:

```
data_mean <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 17, # As many columns as experimental conditions plus one for "Time(h)"
                            nrow = nrow(data)))
```

Copied the data corresponding to time:

```
data_mean[,1] <- data[,1]
```

And attempted to populate the dataframe by assigning the mean of every condition minus the mean of the blanks to each column:

```
data_mean[,2] <- rowMeans(data[,5:8])-rowMeans(data[,2:4])
data_mean[,3] <- rowMeans(data[,9:12])-rowMeans(data[,2:4])
data_mean[,4] <- rowMeans(data[,13:16])-rowMeans(data[,2:4])
data_mean[,5] <- rowMeans(data[,17:20])-rowMeans(data[,2:4])
```

and so on.

Is there an easier way to do this rather than typing the same code over and over?

Answer (score 0):

```
res <- sapply(split.default(data[, -1], seq(ncol(data) - 1)%/%4), rowSums)
res[,-1] - res[,1] # Should give you all the differences above
```

example:

```
 data <- data.frame(matrix(1:200, 10))
 res <- sapply(split.default(data[, -1], seq(ncol(data) - 1)%/%4), rowSums)
 res[,-1] - res[,1] 
        1   2   3   4
 [1,] 161 321 481 641
 [2,] 162 322 482 642
 [3,] 163 323 483 643
 [4,] 164 324 484 644
 [5,] 165 325 485 645
 [6,] 166 326 486 646
 [7,] 167 327 487 647
 [8,] 168 328 488 648
 [9,] 169 329 489 649
[10,] 170 330 490 650
```

and you can check:

```
 rowSums(data[, 5:8]) - rowSums(data[,2:4])
 [1] 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 # first column

 rowSums(data[, 9:12]) - rowSums(data[,2:4])
 [1] 321 322 323 324 325 326 327 328 329 330 # second column
```